# Tor-Messenger : Recieved unexpected data

Tags: chat

I am new to Tor Messenger.Tried using XMPP on Tor Mesenger. I have registered an ID on ulloo.net.
When I try to connect to this account it shows **Error: Recieved Unexpected Data**

ID:(id)

domain:www.ulloo.net

password:(password)

Everything else is default.

I am open to new suggestion regarding servers and all.

Comment: Having *www.* in the domain looks wrong to me. It should just be the domain part of your JID, e.g. if you're *foo@ulloo.net* then the domain should be *ulloo.net*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this on Tor Messenger, I can confirm that this is due to the domain being incorrect.

Your JID is `user@ulloo.net`, where username is `user` and the domain is `ulloo.net`. I create an account with this server and tried to set up the account with the domain as `www.ulloo.net` which resulted in the same error as you received.

However, adding the account with the more normal `ulloo.net` (*without* `www.`) in Tor Messenger resulted in a successful connection.

Comment: Hope you can help with this [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/16673/20584?stw=2) too.

Comment: Help me with [this](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/350/20584) too.